# preimage of a point set under a measurable function is measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Rudin defines measurable functions as:

[image: Rudin's definition of measurable function].

In the proof of theorem 1.9.e:

[image: Theorem 1.9.e]

[image: Proof][1]

Rudin states that the set E is measurable but provides no hint.

I was wondering if it has to do with the fact that $\{0\}$ can be obtained from intersection of countable open balls centered at $0$, with their radius tending to $0$.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of a measurable function? $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable for all open $U \subset \mathbb R$? Well, $\{ 0 \}$ is closed, so $\mathbb R - \{ 0\}$ is open, so...

Comment: So $[f^{-1}(\{0\})]^{c} = f^{-1}(\mathbb{C}-\{0\})$ is measurable $=>$ $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is measurable. Much more straightforward than I thought.

Comment: That's exactly right!